# Using HTTP URIs as identifiers of resources in RESTful web API

Tags: web-services, rest, uri

Usually to retrieve a resource one uses:

```
GET http://ws.mydomain.com/resource/123212
```

But what if your item IDs are HTTP URIs?:

```
GET http://ws.mydomain.com/resource/http://id.someotherdomain.com/SGX.3211
```

Browsers replace two slashes with one, and the request turns into:

```
GET http://ws.mydomain.com/resource/http:/id.someotherdomain.com/SGX.3211
```

which will not work.

URI encoding the "http://id.someotherdomain.com/SGX.3211" -part results in HTTP 400 - Bad request.

Is there a best practice for handling this?

---

Edit:

Then of course if we would need to have (I don't at the moment) request in form:

> resources/*ID*/collections/*ID*

and all IDs are HTTP URIs, things get out of hand... Possibly one could do something like this and parse the contents inside the curly braces:

> `resources/{http://id...}/collections/{http://id...}`

Comment: I'm assuming that the other system's URIs are stable enough to use and aren't subject to change from under you?

Comment: Hi, They are as stable as any other unique (numeric) identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the other system's URI, and then pass the value as a query parameter:

```
GET http://ws.mydomain.com/resource?ref=http%3A%2F%2Fid.someotherdomain.com%2FSGX.3211
```

Ugly looking, but no one said that URIs used in a REST architecture have to be beautiful. :)

By the way, a GET actually looks like this when it's sent:

```
GET /resource?ref=http%3A%2F%2Fid.someotherdomain.com%2FSGX.3211 HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.mydomain.com
```

**UPDATE**: apparently you no longer have to encode "/" and "?" within a query component. From [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
> within the query component.  Beware that some older, erroneous
> implementations may not handle such data correctly when it is used as
> the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1), apparently
> because they fail to distinguish query data from path data when
> looking for hierarchical separators.  However, as query components are
> often used to carry identifying information in the form of "key=value"
> pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to another URI, it
> is sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-encoding those
> characters.

So you could legally do this:

```
GET /resource?ref=id.someotherdomain.com/SGX.3211 HTTP/1.1
Host: ws.mydomain.com
```

Comment: This is probably what I'll have to end up doing, but it isn't entirely "restulful" -- not that I mind that at all. Lets see if there will be any other suggestions.

Comment: What REST constraint is this violating that doesn't make this RESTful?